# UIAlertView Show Once

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

I know this might sound strange, ive had this working in a previous app and now in my present app cant get it to work using the same code.  Im trying to show an Alert View just once when the app is launched uisng:

```
 if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"]]){

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}



 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Text here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];
```

Would someone mind checking incase I have done something silly here, I have cross checked it against my app where this is working and all seems the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show alert inside if block

```
if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"alert"]]){

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"alert"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Text here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alert show];

}
```

or use

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"alertShownOnce"] == NO)
{
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Text here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"alertShownOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you very much for that, and the fast reply-sorted!

Comment: Will do i've got to wait 9 mins until it will let me accept answer, It hasnt accounted for your lighting fast response :-)